# django :: How to style a CheckboxSelectMultiple in a form?

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

forms.py

```
class FormEntry(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = ['name','price','share']
    widgets = {
      'share':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }
```

after passing it into a template:

```
<ul id="id_share">
<li><label for="id_share_0"><input id="id_share_0" name="share" type="checkbox" value="2"> lily</label></li>
<li><label for="id_share_1"><input id="id_share_1" name="share" type="checkbox" value="1"> rabbit</label></li>
</ul>
```

now i want to get rid of the ul and li, also, I would like to use bootstrap3's button group to style it,
something like this

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="id_share_0" name="share" type="checkbox" value="2"> aaa
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="id_share_1" name="share" type="checkbox" value="1"> bbb
  </label>
</div>
```

It would be ideal if someone can give me a general solution, instead of passing specific values from views.py, my idea is to write a widget, but I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of Django 1.6, [you can loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"> 
{% for checkbox in myform.shares %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
    {{ checkbox.tag }} {{ checkbox.choice_label }}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I just spent 2 hours searching for this solution!

Comment: grrrr. `tag` needs better documentation. Thank you!!